# How to create a function which accepts each 1 argument as either one type or the other?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a function which accepts 3 arguments, and each argument can be either something to pass to the `open` function, which my function will pass to `open` and then work with it, or it can be a file object, then my function just works with it without the need to open it.

So, it's something like this

```
def work_with_files(file1, file2, file3):
    files_to_close = []
    file_objects = []
    try:
        for file in (file1, file2, file3):
            if not is_file_object(file):
                opened_file = open(file.argument_for_open)
                file_objects.append(opened_file)
                files_to_close.append(opened_file)
            else:
                file_objects.append(file.file_object)
        work_with_files(file_objects)
    finally:
        for file in files_to_close:
            file.close()
```

In C++ I would use `boost::variant`, in haskell I would probably use `Either`. What's the most pythonic way to do this? What should I pass as arguments, and how should `is_file_object` work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `contextlib.ExitStack` (so fileobjs are automatically closed inside a `with`) and generalise your function, if it's a string - then pass it to `open` otherwise assume it's already a file-like object that has a suitable `.close()`...

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

def work_with_files(*args):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        fileobjs = [
            stack.enter_context(open(obj) if isinstance(obj, str) else obj)
            for obj in args
        ]
        # do something with fileobjs list
```

Where the do something might be like:

```
from itertools import chain

for line in chain.from_iterable(fileobjs):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance` function :

```
isinstance(file_name,file)
```

> [isinstance(object, classinfo)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)
>
> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. Also return true if classinfo is a type object (new-style class) and object is an object of that type or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

Also as :

> File objects are implemented using C’s stdio package and can be created with the built-in open() function.

You can use a try-except statement to deal with `file objects`:

```
try:
  open('file-name')
except IOError:
  #do stuff
```

Comment: What if it's not actually a file but a file-like object like StringIO?

Comment: @CrabMan i have not any idea mayve StringIO module can help you https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO

Comment: I don't actually care about StringIO. I just want to be able to pass any file-like object to the function.

Comment: You can use `isinstance` to see if its a string, in which case you pass it to `open`, and otherwise treat it as a file-like object

Comment: @Dannnno if you read the documentation for `open`, you can see that it can either be a string or an integer. Anyway I would prefer a more universal way - maybe some nice way to pass the argument itself and a tag which decides if it should be used as a file object or not.

Comment: So have another check for if its an integer.  Alternatively, change the way you pass arguments so that there is a list of file-like objects and a list of things you'd pass to open, then handle them separately.  Or do your preprocessing on your own and open everything before, then pass it into your function

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to check the parameter type, you could use the try-except construct to do exactly what you want:

```
def work_with_files(file1, file2, file3):

    # ensure that each file* variable is a file-like object
    try: file1 = open(file1)  # if it opens, then file1 was a filepath
    except: pass  # else, file1 was already a file-like object

    try: file2 = open(file2)
    except: pass

    try: file3 = open(file3)
    except: pass

    do_stuff_with_files(file1, file2, file3)
    for f in (file1, file2, file3): f.close()  # close the files
```

Comment: As it stands, this will recurse infinitely. You want to do closes in a finally block, and generally only close them where you opened them.

Comment: @Lattyware: oops! good catch. I meant to say `do_stuff_with_files`. Fixed now. Thanks for the head's up!